# Ruby on rails - create Invitation on Project page without render new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I try to create a project page with a form to send invitation to other users. The Owner (who have created the project) can invite other users to participate to the project.

Right now, Here is the code :

**views/projects/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
    <h3> <%= @project.title %> </h3>
    <h6> Créé par <%= link_to @project.owner.username, user_path(@project.owner) %> </h6>
    <hr>
    <h3> Inviter des utilisateurs au projet </h3>

    <!-- form for search users -->
    <%= form_tag new_invite_path, method: :post, :class => 'form-inline' do %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], size: 30, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <%= submit_tag 'Ajouter au projet', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
    <!-- end form for search users -->

    <!-- display users results -->
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <p> <%= user.username %> | <%= user.email %> </p>
    <% end %>
    <!-- end display results -->

</div>
```

**controllers/projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @project = Project.find(params[:id])
        @users = User.search(params[:search])
    end

    def new
        @project = Project.new
    end

    def create
        @project = Project.new(project_params)
        @project.owner = current_user
        @project.members = []
        if @project.save
            puts @project
            redirect_to user_path(current_user)
        else
            puts 'something went wrong'
            puts @project.errors.full_messages
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
    def project_params
        params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, :client, :deadline, :owner, :members)
    end
end
```

On the project page, I have an Ajax form to find all the users, with their username and email. 
Now, when I submit this form, I want to create an invitation (a notification, but I haven't begin the notification system). So, I have created this **model** :

```
class Invite
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :email

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :sender_id, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient_id, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

And a **controller** :

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController

    def new 
        @invite = Invite.new(email: params[:search], sender_id: current_user.id)
        byebug
        @invite.save
    end

    def create
        @invite = Invite.new(params[:search])
        if @invite.save
            flash[:success] = 'the invitation is send'
            redirect_to user_path(current_user)
        else
            render 'projects/show'
        end
    end

end
```

So as you can see, I want to save the invite in my db (MongoDB -> Mongoid), but when I submit the form (on the project/show page), I have this error :

```
No route matches [POST] "/invites/new"
```

It's normal, but I want to know :

1. how to insert data in my database without rendering a view ?
2. how to have access to user ID with the email adresse ? (which is in the DB)

Thank you !

NB: don't hesitate to ask if you need more code to answer

Comment: You want to point your form action to the `create` path and not `new`. As per Rails Restful conventions the `new` action will respond to a `GET` request, and not a `POST` request. To reach the `create` method with a `POST`(form submission) you should change the path to `invites_path`

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim thank you for this information ! If you look the invites_controller, how could I store `@invite ` ? and how could I have access to the project_id, and the id of the recipient, depending of his email ?

Comment: What I would do in such case is nest the `invites` resources inside projects in the route file and change the form to point to that nested route. I don't know why you particularly chose to use a `form_tag` instead of a `form_for` and use actual invite fields(like email) to create a new invite. You'll have to change a couple of things using your current approach. The form action should point to `project_invites_path(@project)` and in `InvitesController#create` you'll have access to `params[:project_id]`. I think you can figure out from there.

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim Thank you for your help mate ! I'm going to try all that, and to anwser, I use form_tag because I've followed the railcast tuto to implement an Ajax search form using redis, and it was a form_tag, but I'm sure that I could use form_for !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can insert the data on the database without rendering anything with this line on the controller `render :nothing => true, :status => 200`
so your create method will be like this

```
def create
    @invite = Invite.new(params[:search])
    if @invite.save
        flash[:success] = 'the invitation is send'
        render :nothing => true, :status => 200
    else
        render 'projects/show'
    end
end
```

and this is wrong `No route matches [POST] "/invites/new"` when you try to create something, you will need to go to create, not the new action, just change the url on the form, because you are pointing to the wrong action.

2) If you have an User model and want to load an user by email, you can do something like this

```
User.find_by_email("the email of the user")
```

this is your model is User and the column where the email is, is named "email"

Comment: thank you for the answer, i use find_by instead of find_by_email and it work great !